# Removing relict lines on lidar DEM raster?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing

I'm relatively new to QGIS. I have a raster DEM with these odd lines for every cell, 5m resolution, is there a way I can smooth the DEM or another method to remove these lines using QGIS.

[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/404811/2856

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried what was suggested in the linked post, but the issue still persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the data type of the DEM you used to create the hillshade you are showing?

Comment: @Redbory, please post your DEM.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, I was just suggesting somewhere in either your processing or symbology that a default resampling method (nearest neighbour) has been applied to the DEM. Which results in those horizontal and vertical lines. Although now I look a little closer, there's some terracing artefacts that are indicative of a DEM generated from contours with a poor choice of interpolation.